# Averaging Repeats in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I am making a dictionary using lines of data in a text file. The first three columns of data become form the key and the data in the fourth column forms the value for the dictionary. The code for that is as follows:

```
def formatter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip(): continue
        yield [to_float(item) for item in line.split()]

 dct1 = {}
 with open('test.txt') as f1:
     for row in formatter(f1):
        dct1[tuple(row[:3])] = row[3]
```

This code works. The problem comes that there are repeats of the key in the file that the data is being pulled from e.g. the file might have the two lines:

```
1  2  3  50
1  2  3  100
```

The final dictionary, dct1, however will only contain the second of these lines: dct1[(1,2,3)]=[100]. What I am trying to do, and can't at the moment, is that each time the program tries to overwrite a key, to instead average the values for the given key i.e. so if the above two lines were read in, the value for the key (1,2,3) would 75 (average of 50 and 100).

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Many thanks

Comment: And what if the key occurs 3 times or more? Still the average?

Comment: Yes. There are varying numbers of repeats in the dataset which complicates the solution somewhat

Comment: Not at all, I find that that makes the solution *simpler*, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the average for multiple keys, you'd need to collect all values *first*, *then* calculate the averages afterwards.

Use `collections.defaultdict` to make collecting values easy:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct1 = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as f1:
    for row in formatter(f1):
       dct1[tuple(row[:3])].append(row[3])

dct1 = {k: sum(v)/len(v) for k, v in dct1.iteritems()}
```

First `dct1` is a dictionary mapping keys to *lists* of values. The dict comprehension then replaces that with a dictionary mapping keys to the averages.

Comment: In the last line of this code I keep getting that: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @user1171835: that makes no sense. Can you insert a `print dict1[dict1.keys()[0]]` before that line to show me what type of values you have now?

Comment: @user1171835: Then you didn't run my code, or you are *re-applying* the list line twice.

Comment: have posted the full code that I now have in an answer below. Will remove it later so as to not in any way take credit for it!

Comment: @user1171835: You are missing the *`.append(row[3])`* part. You are *replacing* the `list` provided by the `defaultdict` instead of adding the `float` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've averaged the first two, finding the third will screw you up, because you won't know whether the value in the dict is a single value or the average of two previous. You'll need to keep the count in the dict as well:

```
for row in formatter(f1):
    key = tuple(row[:3])
    if key not in dct1:
        dct1[key] = (1, row[3])
    else:
        val = dct1[key]
        dct1[key] = (val[0] + 1, (val[0] * val[1] + row[:3]) / (val[0] + 1))
```

Now each element in the dict has a count and a average. Instead of using dct1[key], you'll have to use dct1[key][1].

Comment: And afterwards you'll have to *remove* the counts again. May as well calculate the average after the fact, since you have to loop through all entries again anyway.

Comment: Only if you need the final dict to be exactly as he specified. Either your way (dict of tuples) or mine build a dict that contains the information he wants, he just has to retrieve it differently. Mine by a simple [1], yours by calculating the average. Mine is faster, yours is probably less likely to accumulate rounding errors.

Comment: Sure, fair enough, if the OP is willing to put up with small rounding errors and extra data in the output, this is a fair solution.